# Avoid temp file in bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to avoid the creation of a temp file (in the example `t12.txt`) using some bash tricks, to no avail.

Suppose two files `t1.txt` and `t2.txt`, with some text lines.

Example of a command working:

```
$ cat t1.txt t2.txt > t12.txt
$ tac t2.txt t1.txt | tac | diff - t12.txt
```

Now I'm trying to avoid the creation of t12.txt using anything, from pipes to weird redirects.

Commands I tried in different orders and tests are things like: `$(cat t1.txt t2.txt)` or `< <(cat t1.txt t2.txt)`.

Any creative suggestion here? Ty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
diff <(cat t1.txt t2.txt) <(tac t2.txt t1.txt)
```

This just creates temporary file descriptors at `/dev/fd` for the outputs of `cat t1.txt t2.txt` and `tac t2.txt t1.txt` respectively.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect. I was mistakenly using `< <(command)`. Why is that again?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `cmd1 < <(cmd2)` redirects the content of the temporary file descriptor, which points to the output of `cmd2`, to stdin for `cmd1`, so it should be equal to `cmd2 | cmd1`.

Comment: It makes sense. The command to investigate this works flawlessly: `diff <(cat t1.txt t2.txt) - < <(tac t2.txt t1.txt | tac)`